# Javascript to implement this functionality?

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I am looking for a javascript / API that can provide me with similar features like the linkedin skills and endorse skills.

I have to create similar functionality like linkedin where users can select attributes and it shows on their profile. (like bubbles)

Their friends can see such attributes that they have selected and they can upload a picture / file against it.

I am looking for any pointers of how it can be displayed in the GUI If there is a script of API that already has such functionality.

Comment: Do you mean the suggestion "bubble" or tags as they're called?

Comment: @James yeah bubbles, tags :) similar to how you add skills in linkedin...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this [jQuery TokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) plugin from James Smith will set you in the right direction?

It's very easy to use, and you can allow custom entry so if the skill isn't listed, they can add it anyway.